# Passenger + Apache is not spawning padrino app

Tags: ruby, apache, passenger, padrino

**Problem**: My application is not starting, I believe it is because **Passenger spawn server** is not working after apache2 has started.

Following is the error after apache2 has started

**/etc/init.d/apache2 start**

**tail -f /var/log/myapp/production.log**

```
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6282 15170/7fb14e35c700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:532 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6282 15178/7f11376e1700 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:422 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6283 15170/7fb153863780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:901 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6284 15178/7f113c972780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:492 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6285 15170/7fb14dada700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6286 15170/7fb14dada700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6286 15178/7f11376e1700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [UstRouter] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6286 15178/7f1136ee0700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6287 15178/7f1136ee0700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6288 15170/7fb11effd700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6289 15170/7fb11effd700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6301 15170/7fb14d258700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.3] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6302 15170/7fb14c9d6700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.4] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6302 15170/7fb14e35c700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6302 15170/7fb14d258700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.3] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6302 15170/7fb11ffff700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.5] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6303 15170/7fb14c9d6700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.4] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6303 15170/7fb11ffff700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.5] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6303 15170/7fb14e35c700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6305 15178/7f113c972780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:523 ]: Passenger UstRouter shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6305 15170/7fb11f7fe700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.6] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6306 15170/7fb11f7fe700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.6] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6645 15205/7f82ee303780 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1291 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6809 15208/7f7693f84780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:982 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6812 15208/7f7693f84780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:235 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.6867 15208/7f7693f84780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:732 ]: Passenger core online, PID 15208
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.7002 15215/7f4b98dd1780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:529 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.7013 15215/7f4b98dd1780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:342 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 15215
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:39.7154 15170/7fb153863780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:967 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6136 13822/7fe0ccef7700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /usr/share/myapp: An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a startup response in time.
  Error ID: 1f651915
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-gY5lcp.html
  Message from application: An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a startup response in time. Please read <a href="https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems">this article</a> for more information about this problem.<br>
<h2>Raw process output:</h2>
(empty)

[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6410 13822/7fe0ed2c2700 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 1-20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 1f651915. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6415 13822/7fe0ed2c2700 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 1-21] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 1f651915. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6416 13822/7fe0eca40700 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 2-20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 1f651915. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6416 13822/7fe0ce7fc700 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 6-19] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 1f651915. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.

PassengerLogLevel 3
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6419 13822/7fe0ed2c2700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6420 13822/7fe0ed2c2700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6420 13822/7fe0cf7fe700 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 4-20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 1f651915. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6422 13822/7fe0cffff700 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 3-20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 1f651915. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6416 13822/7fe0ceffd700 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 5-20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 1f651915. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6424 13822/7fe0eca40700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6424 13822/7fe0eca40700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6426 13822/7fe0ce7fc700 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 6-20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 1f651915. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6427 13822/7fe0cffff700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.3] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6428 13822/7fe0cffff700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.3] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6430 13822/7fe0ce7fc700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.6] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6431 13822/7fe0ce7fc700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.6] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6435 13822/7fe0cf7fe700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.4] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6435 13822/7fe0ceffd700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.5] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6436 13822/7fe0cf7fe700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.4] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.6436 13822/7fe0ceffd700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.5] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 15:56:41.7198 13822/7fe0f27c9780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:967 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
```

Apache: 2.4

Phusion Passenger: 5.0.30

Debian: 9 (Stretch)

Ruby framework: Padrino

**/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.load**

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby-flo/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby-flo/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/lib/ruby-flo/bin/ruby
  PassengerLoadShellEnvvars off
  PassengerSpawnMethod smart
</IfModule>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp.conf**

```
PassengerLogLevel 3
PassengerDebugLogFile /var/log/myapp/production.log
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby-flo

Listen 28850
<VirtualHost *:28850>
   AddDefaultCharset utf-8
   DocumentRoot /usr/share/myapp/public
   PassengerAppRoot /usr/share/myapp
   KeepAlive On
   KeepAliveTimeout 5
   MaxKeepAliveRequests 1000

   SetEnv DEPLOY_ENV production
   SetEnv PADRINO_ENV production

</VirtualHost>

Listen 28852
<VirtualHost *:28852>
   AddDefaultCharset utf-8
   DocumentRoot /usr/share/myapp/public
   PassengerAppRoot /usr/share/myapp

   SSLEngine On
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/fk-flo-rubycas-server/ssl/cert.pem

  SetEnv SUPPLY_CHAIN_COMPANY b2b
  SetEnv FLO_GEM_SERVER http://10.85.147.182/
  SetEnv DEPLOY_ENV production
  SetEnv PADRINO_ENV production
  SetEnv NO_AUTH
  SetEnv MULTI
  SetEnv INFER_HEADER
  SetEnv LDAP_PERM
  SetEnv MULTI_TENANCY_ENABLED
  SetEnv DISABLE_COMPANY_CHECK
  SetEnv BAG_LABEL_MAPPINGS

</VirtualHost>

<Directory /usr/share/myapp/public>
   Require all Granted
   AllowOverride all
   Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

**$ passenger-memory-stats**

```
Version: 5.0.30
Date   : 2019-03-25 16:18:12 +0530
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_IN:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_IN:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US").

---------- Apache processes ----------
PID    PPID   VMSize    Private  Name
--------------------------------------
15955  1      98.7 MB   0.5 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
15990  15955  379.0 MB  0.5 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
15993  15955  379.0 MB  0.5 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
### Processes: 3
### Total private dirty RSS: 1.43 MB


-------- Nginx processes --------

### Processes: 0
### Total private dirty RSS: 0.00 MB


----- Passenger processes ------
PID    VMSize     Private  Name
--------------------------------
15958  414.8 MB   0.9 MB   Passenger watchdog
15961  1310.1 MB  2.4 MB   Passenger core
15969  423.0 MB   0.9 MB   Passenger ust-router
### Processes: 3
### Total private dirty RSS: 4.18 MB
```

Comment: The error message says: _"Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-gY5lcp.html"_. Did you check that error document? Please post that too.

Comment: @spickermann, "An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a startup response in time. Please read this article for more information about this problem." is the error message from the HTML file, the other data is the environment variables.